Login to tiktok seller account using selenium
I am using below code to login tiktok seller account. But, It is working in mac properly even on headless mode.
When i am running inside docker i am getting below error.
ERROR:setup:Login attempt 3 failed: Message: element not interactable

Code to login tiktok seller account:
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import os
import logging
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


logger = logging.getLogger('setup')


def setup_driver(profile_id=None):
    # Initialize Chrome options
    options = uc.ChromeOptions()

    # Optional: Set the binary location explicitly if required (uncomment and update this path as needed)
    # options.binary_location = "/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome"  # For macOS
    options.binary_location = "/usr/bin/google-chrome"  # For Linux/Docker environments

    # Set Chrome options for better automation experience
    options.add_argument("--start-maximized")  # Open the browser maximized
    options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")  # Disable any popups that may interrupt
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.popups": 1,
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1
    })

    # Additional Chrome options to optimize performance and stability
    options.add_argument("--disable-background-networking")
    options.add_argument("--disable-background-timer-throttling")
    options.add_argument("--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows")
    options.add_argument("--disable-breakpad")
    options.add_argument("--disable-client-side-phishing-detection")
    options.add_argument("--disable-default-apps")
    options.add_argument("--disable-hang-monitor")
    options.add_argument("--disable-prompt-on-repost")
    options.add_argument("--disable-sync")
    options.add_argument("--metrics-recording-only")
    options.add_argument("--no-first-run")
    options.add_argument("--safebrowsing-disable-auto-update")
    options.add_argument("--password-store=basic")
    options.add_argument("--use-mock-keychain")
    options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")  # Disable annoying info bars in Chrome
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")  # Avoid detection as a bot
    options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")  # Fix issues in some environments
    options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")  # Handle resource issues
    options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")  # Disable GPU acceleration
    options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")  # Avoid port conflicts
    # Uncomment this line to run in headless mode (for server or Docker environments)
    options.add_argument("--headless")

    try:
        if profile_id:
            base_profile_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "chrome_profiles")
            profile_path = os.path.join(base_profile_dir, f"profile_{profile_id}")
            
            # Check if profile already exists; if it exists, we load it, otherwise we create it
            if not os.path.exists(profile_path):
                logger.info(f"Profile directory for {profile_id} does not exist, creating...")
                os.makedirs(profile_path, exist_ok=True)
            else:
                logger.info(f"Profile directory for {profile_id} already exists, loading...")
            
            # Use specific Chrome profile
            options.add_argument(f"--user-data-dir={profile_path}")  
        # Initialize the Chrome driver with the defined options
        driver = uc.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
        return driver
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Failed to set up Chrome driver: {e}")
        print(f"Failed to set up Chrome driver: {e}", flush=True)
        return None



def login_to_tiktok(driver, email, password, max_retries=3):
    # Open TikTok Seller login page
    driver.get("https://seller-us-accounts.tiktok.com/account/login")

    # Wait for and click the 'Email' tab to switch to email login if not already selected
    email_tab = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'tab')]//span[text()='Email']"))
    )
    if email_tab.is_selected():
        print("Email tab already selected")
    else:
        email_tab.click()

    logger.info("Logging in to TikTok Seller account...")
    print("Logging in to TikTok Seller account...", flush=True)

    # Wait for the email input field to be visible and interactable
    email_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Enter your email address']"))
    )
    email_input.clear()
    email_input.send_keys(email)

    logger.info("Email entered")
    print("Email entered", flush=True)

    # Wait for the password input field to be interactable
    password_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@placeholder='Enter your password']"))
    )
    password_input.clear()
    password_input.send_keys(password)

    logger.info("Password entered")
    print("Password entered", flush=True)

    # Click the login button
    login_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[contains(text(), 'Log in')]"))
    )
    login_button.click()

    logger.info("Login button clicked")
    print("Login button clicked", flush=True)

    # Wait for the login process to complete by checking for a post-login element (like user dashboard)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#dashboard_element_selector"))  # Update this selector
    )

    logger.info("Logged in successfully")
    return True  # Login successful, exit the loop




def login_sellers_with_profile(self):
    email = self.email
    password = self.password

    driver = setup_driver(profile_id=email)
    
    # Check if the user is already logged in by visiting the homepage
    if self.is_logged_in(driver):
        logger.info(f"✋ ✋ ✋ {email} is already logged in, skipping login.")
        print(f"✋ ✋ ✋ {email} is already logged in, skipping login.", flush=True)
        return driver
    
    logger.info(f"   Logging in {email}...")
    print(f"   Logging in {email}...", flush=True)
    # If not logged in, perform the login process
    login_response = login_to_tiktok(driver, email, password)
    print(f"   Login response: {login_response}", flush=True)
    if login_response:
        logger.info(f"✔ ✔ ✔ Logged in successfully to {email}")
        print(f"✔ ✔ ✔ Logged in successfully to {email}", flush=True)
    else:
        logger.info(f"✘ ✘ ✘ Login failed for {email}")
        print(f"✘ ✘ ✘ Login failed for {email}", flush=True)
        driver.quit()
        return None
    
    return driver

I am using docker inside linux vm to login this. I am getting below error.
I shared the driver setup code too.
Let me know if anything else is required.

First, check which element is not interactable. Then you will know which code to fix. Once you know the place, I suggest first to try to increase the wait, maybe the element is still invisible or covered by another element. Second, maybe try to use driver.execute_script() or set the focus to the element earlier, by additional click or scrolling to the element.
